# Equating both sides of the equation

Tags: equation-solving

I want to verify that two equations are equal. I have comparing the left and right hand side, which should print 1 or 0, but it doesn't work, it just re-prints the equations.

Comment: Probably mathematica can't simplify your expression further. Can you give some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to  simplify the two sides of the expression with `FullSimplify[x1 == x2]`